# joint histogram between 2 image

Tags: image, opencv, histogram

Would like to ask if anyone has or can point me to a fast implementation of a function that calculates the joint histogram between two images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Joint histogram or cumulated histogram? For the latter, [`calcHist`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calchist#calchist) with the accumulate flags set to true will do the job.

For the first case, reading [this link](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/68690) might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, have done the same method previously but wondering if there is any faster code implementation or any comparison cases...I am wondering if I have been implementing this efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the joint histogram between multiple images works directly with cv2.calcHist() as well.
The trick is to pass an array of the images you want to have in the joint histogram. Then, you have to select the channels that should end up in the histogram. The channel numbering is described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=calchist#cv2.calcHist).

This is a short example code in Python that calculates the joint histogram between im1 and im2:

```
im1 = cv2.imread(im1_path, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
im2 = cv2.imread(im2_path, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
h = cv2.calcHist( [im1, im2], [0, 1], None, [256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256] )
```